# Installation error with pip install tokenizers==0.12.1 – Compatibility issue with Python 3.6.15 and Rust 1.72.0

Tags: python, compiler-errors, rust-cargo, huggingface-tokenizers

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYA70.png)

I'm encountering an issue while trying to install the tokenizers package with version 0.12.1 using the command pip install tokenizers==0.12.1. My Python version is 3.6.15, and the Rust compiler version is 1.72.0.

I've attempted to resolve the problem by experimenting with different versions of Python and Rust, but unfortunately, I haven't been successful. The error message I'm receiving is [insert error message here].

I would appreciate any insights or guidance on how to address this compatibility issue and successfully install the required version of the tokenizers package.

Thank you in advance for your help!

I am facing challenges while attempting to install version 0.12.1 of the tokenizers package using the command pip install tokenizers==0.12.1. My Python version is 3.6.15, and I'm using Rust compiler version 1.72.0.

The encountered errors include mutable warnings and a casting issue. Specifically:

```
warning: variable does not need to be mutable
     --> tokenizers-lib\src\models\unigram\model.rs:265:21
      |
  265 |                 let mut target_node = &mut best_path_ends_at[key_pos];
      |                     ----^^^^^^^^^^^
      |                     |
      |                     help: remove this `mut`
  ...
  error: casting `&T` to `&mut T` is undefined behavior, even if the reference is unused, consider instead using an `UnsafeCell`
     --> tokenizers-lib\src\models\bpe\trainer.rs:526:47
      |
  522 |                     let w = &words[*i] as *const _ as *mut _;
      |                             -------------------------------- casting happened here
  ...
  526 |                         let word: &mut Word = &mut (*w);
      |                                               ^^^^^^^^^
      |
      = note: for more information, visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html>
      = note: `#[deny(invalid_reference_casting)]` on by default

warning: `tokenizers` (lib) generated 3 warnings
error: could not compile `tokenizers` (lib) due to the previous error; 3 warnings emitted
```

I have attempted to address the mutable warnings by removing unnecessary mut keywords, but I am unsure how to resolve the casting issue and would appreciate guidance on successfully installing the tokenizers package.

Thank you for any assistance you can provide!

Comment: I think I saw the same problem in other question few days ago.

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly.
Text allows for quick copy and pictures do not.
[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [cargo rustc failed with code 101 - Could not build wheels for tokenizers, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77265938/cargo-rustc-failed-with-code-101-could-not-build-wheels-for-tokenizers-which)

Answer (score 1):

You don’t say *why* you want to install `tokenizers==0.12.1` specifically, but I found a project that includes that in its requirements: [`Stability-AI/generative-models`](https://github.com/Stability-AI/generative-models). I tried to install this myself following their instructions, on Python 3.11.6 and Rust 1.74.0, and was able to reproduce your error.

The issue seems to be that the Rust compiler (`rustc`) became more strict at some point. `tokenizers` was fixed to work with this strictness [as of version 0.14.1](https://github.com/huggingface/tokenizers/issues/1359). (That Github issue suggests the issue appeared with Rust 1.73.0, and that 1.72.1 worked, but this would disagree with your listed version of 1.72.0.)

I was able to make the installation succeed by changing the requirements file (`requirements/pt2.txt`) to require `tokenizers>=0.14.1` **and** `transformers>=4.36`. (It formerly required `transformers==4.19.1`, but that version demands `tokenizers<0.13`, producing a dependency conflict.)

⚠️ I can’t say whether the project actually *works*, only that it *compiled and installed* with this change. ⚠️

The same issue is reported in this question: [cargo rustc failed with code 101 - Could not build wheels for tokenizers, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77265938/cargo-rustc-failed-with-code-101-could-not-build-wheels-for-tokenizers-which). According to the top-voted answer there, it is possible to force the use of an older (more permissive) version of `rustc` by way of the `RUSTUP_TOOLCHAIN` environment variable.